# Cannot instantiate interface Company\Module\Api\Quote\Data\AddressInterface

Tags: custom-attributes, custom-field, address-interface

Iam using Magento 2.3.5-p2. I add custom field in the cart and checkout page which is successfully showing there.

In app\code\Company\Module\etc\di.xml

```
<preference for="Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressInterface" type="Company\Module\Api\Quote\Data\AddressInterface"/>
```

In app\code\Company\Module\Api\Quote\Data\AddressInterface.php

```
<?php
namespace Company\Module\Api\Quote\Data;

use Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressInterface as MagentoDataAddressInterface;

interface AddressInterface extends MagentoDataAddressInterface
{
    const KEY_SUBDISTRICT = 'subdistrict_id';

    public function getSubdistrictId();

    public function setSubdistrictId($subdistrictId);
}
```

But while getting shipping estimate, it was error

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface Company\Module\Api\Quote\Data\AddressInterface in C:\wamp64\www\magento2-2\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer.php:50
```

I already

- Delete /generated/code
- Delete /static/frontend
- php bin\magento cache:clean

Answer (score 0):

You cannot override any interface in such way.

**If you have to use extension attribute for this case.**

**`extension_attributes.xml` code look like:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressInterface">
        <attribute code="subdistrict_id" type="int" />
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

Using extension attribute you can update and get data for your custom  field.See https://store.fooman.co.nz/blog/an-introduction-to-extension-attributes.html

Comment: If I remove the preference from di.xml and using extension_attributes.xml above, I got error `Property "SubdistrictId" does not have accessor method "getSubdistrictId" in class "Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressInterface".`